# casperjs - Using casper.options and specifically injecting casper clientScripts using casper.tester

Tags: casperjs

The [docs strate](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#captureSelector) you can pass an `options` object to `casperjs.create()` including js clientScripts to inject to the client page.

The [docs also state](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#captureSelector) that you shouldn't casper.create  instance in a test file.

The docs don't state (at least I couldn't find it) how to use an `options` object with the casper.tester class. I did try to do something like:

```
casper.options = {
    clientScripts:[
        '../testlib/sinon-1.7.3.js'
        ],
    logLevel:"warning",
    verbose:true

};
```

Before `casper.test.begin` but it broke the test.

putting it between the test.begin and casper.start.

```
casper.test.begin('Basic index.html elements test',14, function suite(test){
    casper.options..etc
    casper.start(url, function(){
    //also tried here
```

and also beneath it also broke the tests

I,ll be glad for any direction with this. Especially with the injection part

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to push the file onto `casper.option.clientScripts` so as not to disrupt the other options that `casper test` sets.

```
casper.options.clientScripts.push("../testlib/sinon-1.7.3.js");
```

Source: [CasperJS mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/casperjs/PMkFz4XVi9s/barca_MMTjMJ)

Comment: but where in the script? before ```test.begin```?, before or after ```casper.start```. something else?

Comment: Wherever you would like; typically you would want it at the top of the script. Just make sure that it is before the page load.

Comment: Note for Casper 1.1 users: while this solution was great in 1.0, it seems that in 1.1 it loads these scripts very late. Scripts from the webpage can load before them. In order to avoid that, one can resort to `casper.on('page.initialized', function(page) {
    if(!page.injectJs('myInjectedCode.js')) {
        this.echo("failed to inject");
    }
});`